# Unable to implement caesar cipher shift correctly (not sure where's the problem)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon-webextensions, caesar-cipher

I am trying to implement caesar cipher in javascript. I learnt the shifting method from here: https://www.thatsoftwaredude.com/content/11425/implementing-a-caesar-cipher-in-javascript.

Basically to perform shift, it first creates a string of letters that are already shifted in place, and then performs 1 to 1 lookup to find the character to replace using index.

The code provided below is part of my web extension.

There are a couple of input fields with IDs, and whenever one of them is modified by user, the cipher() function will be run, and the return value will be updated on the output field (#encrypt-preview).

```
$("#encrypt-plaintext, #encrypt-shiftInput, #encrypt-strategy, #encrypt-foreign-character-option").on('change input', function () {
        $("#encrypt-preview").html(cipher(1));
    });
```

This is the cipher() function. (Focus on case 1 that will run the encrypt() function).

```
function cipher(type) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var cipher_notify = "Fill up the required fields<br><br><br><br>";

    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            return encrypt(alphabet, cipher_notify);
        case 2:
            return decrypt(alphabet, cipher_notify);
        default:
    }
}
```

Plaintext is the text to be encrypted. Shift is the shift value. If the form's input fields are not empty (checks everytime when user modifies the input fields), it will use for loop to generate a new alphabet list according to shift value.

The logic is correct, I tried it on some online editor and it returns the correct output (example: **abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz** with shift **1** will return **bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza**).

However, when I implement it in my code, it returns some weird string (example: **abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz** with shift **1** will return **blvfpzjtdnxhrblvfpzjtdnxhr**).

```
//encrypt function
function encrypt(alphabet, cipher_notify) {

    const foreignChars = /[ `!@#$0123456789%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;

    var plaintext = document.getElementById("encrypt-plaintext").value;
    var shift = document.getElementById("encrypt-shiftInput").value;
    var strategy = document.getElementById("encrypt-strategy").value;
    var foreignCharOption = document.getElementById("encrypt-foreign-character-option").value;

    var oldalpha = alphabet;
    var newalpha = "";
    var newalphaUpper = "";
    var message = cipher_notify;

    //encryption logic
    if (plaintext.length > 0 && shift !== "" && strategy.toLowerCase() !== "" && foreignCharOption.toLowerCase() !== "") {

        message = "";

        //generate new alphabet list
        for (let i = 0; i < oldalpha.length; i++) {

            //working code
            let offset = (i + shift) % oldalpha.length;
            newalpha += oldalpha[offset];
            newalphaUpper += oldalpha[offset].toUpperCase();

        }

        return newalpha; //i use this temporarily to double check what it returned
...
```

I have been thinking for hours and I still can't find the problem source (new to javascript + web dev). Help please!

Comment: Okay wait. I wrapped the document.getElementById("encrypt-shiftInput").value with a parseInt(). It worked!

Comment: you have to change `shift !== ""` too now

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski Thanks for reminding! I have now changed it to `!Number.isNaN(shift)`.